# NightwatchJS Unable to locate element using CSS Selector

Tags: javascript, css, testing, nightwatch.js

I've currently got a section of a web site that looks like so:

```
<form id="product_form" method="POST" action="/cart/add" role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div>
        <img class="product-image" src="/static/images/products/4388801543.jpg" width="500px" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 product-variants other_options">
      <h1 itemprop="name" class="product-single__title h3 uppercase">Samburu Shorts - Mens</h1>
      <p class="product-single__price product-single__price-product-template">
        <span id="ProductPrice" itemprop="price" content="$55.95">$55.95</span>
      </p>
      <input type="radio" name="variant_id" class="hidden" id="14903870471" value="14903870471" onclick="enableSubmit()"><label for="14903870471" class="option text-center  selector size-value">29x11 Sand-Grey</label>
      <input type="radio" name="variant_id" class="hidden" id="16304664135" value="16304664135" onclick="enableSubmit()"><label for="16304664135" class="option text-center  selector size-value">29x11 Aubergine-Grey</label>
      <input type="radio" name="variant_id" class="hidden" id="16304665799" value="16304665799" onclick="enableSubmit()"><label for="16304665799" class="option text-center  selector size-value">34x7-5 Sand-Grey</label>
      <div class="product-add">
        <button id="add-to-cart" class="addItemToCart btn addToCart-btn product-form__cart-submit" disabled="" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
      </div>
      <div class="social-sharing">
        <a target="_blank" href="#" class="btn clear btn--share share-facebook" title="Share on Facebook">
        <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0281/7544/t/59/assets/img_share_fb.png?3517946130637841476">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Share on Facebook</span>
        </a>
        <a target="_blank" href="#" class="btn clear btn--share share-twitter" title="Tweet on Twitter">
        <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0281/7544/t/59/assets/img_share_twitter.png?3517946130637841476">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Tweet on Twitter</span>
        </a>
        <a target="_blank" href="#" class="btn clear btn--share share-pinterest" title="Pin on Pinterest">
        <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0281/7544/t/59/assets/img_share_pin.png?3517946130637841476">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Pin on Pinterest</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'm scripting out a test through NightwatchJS where I am trying to select one of the radio buttons so I can automate a user experience.  The code test block that I have written out is as follows:

```
'Check that widget loaded on new product page' : function(browser) {
   browser
      .waitForElementVisible('#monsoon-inline-reco-div-ul', longWait, () => {
      })
      .elements('css selector', '#monsoon-inline-reco-div-ul li', (results) => {
         browser.assert.equal(results.value.length, 4);
      })
      .click('#product_form > div > div:nth-child(2) > input[type=radio]')
      .pause(longWait)
      .end();
  }
```

The line in question is the click command. I keep getting errors about how the script cannot find the element given the css selector.  I've tested this in the console in the browser itself using `document.querySelector('#product_form > div > div:nth-child(2) > input[type=radio]').click()` and the radio button is clicked.  Could use some thoughts on something I might be doing wrong because I've been working this for a couple hours now and have tried a variety of different things.

Comment: If `nightwatch.js` behaves like jQuery, then your `.click` is operating on the subset of elements returned by the `.elements` function call - which means that the selector won't return the same results as the document.  i.e.  It's not doing `document.querySelector`, it's doing `someElement.querySelector`.   (since `#product_form` is not a descendant of `#monsoon-inline-reco-div-ul` there's no surprise here)

Comment: From the [API Reference](http://nightwatchjs.org/api): "The located elements will be returned as WebElement JSON objects".  Sounds like the above comment has a good chance of being the case.  Try just ending your chain after the `.elements()` call and starting a new chain with `browser.click(...`

Comment: I've tried using `input[type=radio]:first-child` as well to ensure there is only one element but there is an error thrown saying pretty much it's trying to find first-child on a null list

Comment: Yes, of course.   You are only searching the direct descendants of `li` items that are descendents of `#monsoon-inline-reco-div-ul`.  Since `#product_form` is not a descendent of `#monsoon-inline-reco-div-ul` your list will always be null

Comment: In fact, I don't see `monsoon-inline-reco-div-ul` in your HTML at all

Comment: @Tibrogargan I'm using a div ID as the starting point to look.  The click should start there and start drilling further into the page.

Comment: Not in your question you're not

Comment: What do you mean I'm not in my question.  I start with `.click(#product_form...`.  That's a div selector using the pound sign.  I also tried ending my chaing and starting a new one and nothing happens.  No errors though

Comment: The CSS selector `#monsoon-inline-reco-div-ul` is literally looking for an element with the ID "monsoon-inline-reco-div-ul".  There is no such element in your HTML

Comment: That line passes just fine.  It's to make sure an element appears on the page.  I didn't upload the HTML for the entire page for the sake of brevity in code example.  The error is on the `click` call.  Everything else in that snippet is working.

Comment: Your call chain is **implicitly**  also chaining CSS selectors.  Since you have not included the relevant HTML it is impossible to tell if your chain of selectors is correct.  What the CSS selector in your `.click` call is doing is **not the same** as `document.querySelector`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173769/discussion-between-michael-platt-and-tibrogargan).